# Pass by value or reference

Tags: java, reference

I know this subject is very beaten, but ...

I'm programming an app for android in java, but I come from c++ , where the question of value or reference is very explicit.
The problem is:

Initially I have a class called **Item** that has a variable **public int ID**.

In a class called **ListingItem**, I have a **static List list** with two **item** added to it, each has assigned to its variable **ID** the value **1**. In this class there is also a function **public static List getList()** that returns **List**, specifically, the List **list** of this class.

In another class, called **Fragment**, I have a **List ItemList** and a function **private List getList()** that returns **List**.

The **getList()** of Fragment class does the following:

```
private List <Item> getList()
{
    List<Item> list = ListingItem.getList() // copy list from ListingItem.list
    List<Item> returnList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    returnList.add(list.get(0);
    returnList.add(list.get(1); // copy to returnList two Item objects from list (that copied from ListingItem.list)

    returnList return;
}
```

Another function of class **Fragment** use **Fragment.getList()** like this:

```
private functionOfFragment()
{
    List<Item> ItemList = getList();

    itemList.get(0).ID = 2;
    itemList.get(1).ID = 2; // changing from 1 to 2
}
```

However, the value of **ListingItem.list.get(0).ID** and **ListingItem.list.get(0).ID** are also the value **2**. How is this possible?

obs: THIS CODE IS ONLY REPRESENTATIVE, THE PROBLEM ISN'T THE SYNTAX ERROS!

Comment: " each has assigned to its variable ID the value 1".  I don't think you really have two objects in your static list.  Do you call "new" twice?

Comment: Need to close parens in `returnList.add(list.get(0);`

Comment: The static List<Item> list from ListingItem have two Item objects, but how Fragment could change its ID value, since it only received copys of the Item objects from ListingItem.list?

Comment: No, @MadPhysicist .. this code is only representative, has no syntax errors

Comment: @Neviat. Still don't post bad code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter passing by value in Java is not the same as in C++.

In Java:

- Parameter passing is *always* by value.
- An object reference is a variable itself, storing the location of an object.
- Passing an object reference *passes its value*.

Therefore an object reference in Java is functionally *like* a pointer, but you cannot dereference and reassign it.

In C++ you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeObj {
public:
    int num;
    SomeObj(int n) {
        num = n;
    }
};

void reassign(SomeObj* obj) {
    *obj = *(new SomeObj(5));
}

int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) {
    SomeObj* obj = new SomeObj(0);

    reassign(obj);

    // prints '5'
    std::cout << obj->num << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You cannot do that in Java. A Java reference variable is not a C++ pointer, not a C++ reference and not a C++ object value.

You can only do this:

```
void reassignLocal(SomeObj* obj) {
    obj = new SomeObj(5);
}
```

And this:

```
void mutateElsewhere(SomeObj* obj) {
    obj->num = 5;
}
```

So creating a new List like the following:

```
static List<SomeObj> shallowCopy(List<SomeObj> input) {
    List<SomeObj> output = new ArrayList<SomeObj>(input.size());

    for (SomeObj obj : input)
        output.add(obj);

    return output;
}
```

Only copies the references from one list to the other. They are the same objects. Mutating `output` elements will mutate `input` elements and vice-versa. To change this you need to actually instantiate new objects.

```
static List<SomeObj> deepCopy(List<SomeObj> input) {
    List<SomeObj> output = new ArrayList<SomeObj>(input.size());

    for (SomeObj obj : input)
        output.add(new SomeObj(obj.num));

    return output;
}
```

Comment: That answered everything very well. Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In Java, pass by value vs. reference is very explicit too. There is only pass-by-value--for everything.

In your example, you retrieve `Item` instances from the `ArrayList`, and *copies* of the references are passed to `returnList.add`. Still, the copies point to the same objects in memory as the originals, and they all can be "dereferenced" with the dot operator.

That's what you are doing when you say `itemList.get(1).ID = 2`. Because `ID` is public, when you dereference, you are accessing the object and setting its value to something new.

So references to objects (and primitives too) are passed by value, but *the objects they reference* can be altered in the manner defined by the class API. That is not the same as pass-by-reference, which is not feasible in a language that manages memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because the variables refer to the same referent. The value of every `java.lang.Object` (e.g. objects not primitives) variable is the reference address (e.g. the "confusing" default `toString()` implementation), I hope that helps! Also, this is backwards `returnList return;`.

Comment: Technically, it's the value of each variable or member field in a program that is a reference. (The "value of every Java Object" is the object.) Only references are assigned, passed, and returned.

Comment: It should really say "The value of every variable reference to a Java Object (object, not primitive) is the object's address."

Comment: So... How can I make a copy of (List<Item>) list.get(0) to (List<Item>) anotherList, if even I do anotherList = list and anotherList.add(list.get(0)) I will take the reference, and when I do: anotherList.get(0).ID = 2, I'm changing the list.get(0).ID too?

Comment: @Neviat Make a copy of the List? Or a copy of the item in the list? Look at [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would say in Java we "pass references by value", except primitives of course. In case of primitives they are itself passed by value.

Comment: Primitives are passed by value, too.

Comment: What? But, if it pass by value, how itemList from Fragment.functionOfFragment changed the value of ListingItem.list?

Comment: @Neviat In Java, an object variable is always a reference. Even in C++ the by value/reference difference is semantically deceptive because pointers are passed by value too. Java is "always pass by value" because you don't get to pick.